# Gmail API: How to get access token?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I am testing the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).

So far I have done the following:

- I have created the project in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0)
- I have enabled the `Gmail API`.
- I have created a new `Client ID` and the `client secret`.
- In my PHP script I have installed the PHP Client library and followed
  the [instructions for the setup in PHP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php).

So now when I run the file quickstart.php it gives a link. When I open it, it appears an authorization page where I authorize my application to access the Gmail API.

**Then it redirects to the Redirect URIs that I have declared in the setup** (adding the code parameter).

In the address bar it appears exactly this:

http://localhost/main/gmail_callback?code=MY_CODE

Where *main* is my controller and *gmail_callback* so far is just a blank function.

And it should be correct since these are my settings:

- Javascript origins: `http://localhost`
- Redirect URIs: `http://localhost/main/gmail_callback`

**What do I do next?**

Comment: Its should contain your handling of the authentication flow.

Comment: What is that exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: not for Gmail sorry.   but most of what you need is in the page you linked quickstart.php contains the authentication stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I was approaching wrongly. Following these instructions is enough to get the tokens:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

The main point is to access the file from the command line and not from the app.

Answer (score 2):

The next step in the flow is to exchange the Authorization Code for an Access Token (which will also include a Refresh Token if you requested offline access). If you use the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to execute the flow manually, you'll be able to see the URLs involved. There is a php library call to do the same thing, but I personally prefer to send my own HTTP rather than use a library. Even if you do use a library, it will still be worth spending a little time to understand the HTTP flow so you can more easily debug any problems you encounter.

Comment: Thank you, i understand better how it works. I have select and authorize Gmail API, exchange authorization code for the access tokens. I have then sent a request to get the messages and get a list of messages in json format. It seems to be fine. So if i understand properly what i need is to exchange the authorization code for the access tokens in my app too. That is what i miss. But how can that be done in my app? Thank you!

Comment: Is this something you'll do for each user to access their own gmail, or is this a one off to access a central account?

Comment: It is the one to access the central account i think

Comment: If it's a one off exercise for a single central account, you can actually do the whole thing in the Oauth Playground without writing a single line of code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic?s=8|2.2789

Answer (score 0):

I made a Oauth Gmail some months ago, I got something like this :

In my callback function :

```
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  return $this->redirect($auth_url);
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = Router::url('/', true).'Users/gmail';
  return $this->redirect($redirect_uri);
}
```

And in my `gmail()` function :

```
public function gmail(){ 
    require APPLIBS.'Google/src/Google'.DS.'autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('../Config/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_LOGIN);
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $oauth_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $data['Profile']['last_name']  = $oauth_service->userinfo->get()->familyName; 
    } 
}
```

`$data['Profile']['last_name']`  contain the last_name of the user, for example.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In the callback there is only that code?
YOur gmail() function is where you send request to the API? (for instance if you want to get the messages?)

Comment: Nop, there is this : public function oauthgmail2callback(){ // Callback
        require APPLIBS.'Google/src/Google'.DS.'autoload.php';
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfigFile('../Config/client_secrets.json');
        $gmailredirecturi = Router::url('/', true).'Users/oauthgmail2callback';
        $client->setRedirectUri($gmailredirecturi);
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_LOGIN);
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
        $client->setAccessType('online');

Comment: Yes it is, for example the $data['Profile']['last_name'] value, etc. Depending on what you're looking for, depending of your $client->addScope / authorization